# How to install gtkmm4?

Tags: 18.04, gtk

I would like to start using `gtkmm4` ASAP!
My development environment is Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10.
I'm trying to follow the guides, but they are incomplete/broken/composed of separate parts and it's really hard to follow them.
On Ubuntu I installed using `jhbuild` successfully, but when I run `pkg-config --cflags gtk4` I get the error:

```
Package 'gtk4' requires 'wayland-protocols >= 1.20' but version of wayland-protocols is 1.13
```

On Windows I installed `gtk4` using MSYS2 but how do I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

After searching [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) for `wayland-procotols`, it seems that the latest packaged version for Ubuntu 18.04 is [1.13-1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/wayland-protocols); for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS it is instead [1.20-1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/wayland-protocols). You should consider upgrading your OS to the latest LTS (a tutorial can be found [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/upgrading-ubuntu-desktop)) or cloning the project from GitHub ([project](https://github.com/wayland-project/wayland-protocols)) and compiling yourself the desired version.